# Meaning of given regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please explain me the meaning of the following regular expression in JavaScript with proper exploration:

```
/^\b_((?:__|[\s\S])+?)_\b|^\*((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?)\*(?!\*)/
```

Comment: You can use a tool like Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) and it will break it down for you

Comment: Does my answer help you? Also make sure you use the given tool to check in the future.

Comment: Do you have further questions?

Comment: What will be the modifications for following regular expression to get a br tag on only \n not 'at two spaces and a \n' i am editing a a markfown editor grammar.

Comment: Regular expression : /^ {2,}\n(?!\s*$)/

Answer (score 1):

This is the meaning.

```
/^\b_((?:__|[\s\S])+?)_\b|^\*((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?)\*(?!\*)/
1st Alternative: ^\b_((?:__|[\s\S])+?)_\b
^ assert position at start of the string
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
_ matches the character _ literally
1st Capturing group ((?:__|[\s\S])+?)
(?:__|[\s\S])+? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: +? Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
1st Alternative: __
__ matches the characters __ literally
2nd Alternative: [\s\S]
[\s\S] match a single character present in the list below
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\S match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
_ matches the character _ literally
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
2nd Alternative: ^\*((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?)\*(?!\*)
^ assert position at start of the string
\* matches the character * literally
2nd Capturing group ((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?)
(?:\*\*|[\s\S])+? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: +? Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
1st Alternative: \*\*
\* matches the character * literally
\* matches the character * literally
2nd Alternative: [\s\S]
[\s\S] match a single character present in the list below
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\S match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
\* matches the character * literally
(?!\*) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
\* matches the character * literally
```

Well, in a really nice form:

[image]

You can check this out at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Answering questions with no research effort reassures the poster that these questions are welcome and will continue to do so to possibly no end. I personally do not think this behaviour should be supported.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I understand. I check the intellect of the OP before answering such questions. FWIW, for this OP, it doesn't matter if I spend 10 mins or lose 2 rep. `:)` Happy to help.